Flutter How to remove openapp ads after user subscribe?
I'm trying to make subscription payments on my Flutter app so that users can choose from them.
first I added three subscription items at Google Play.
then I made the code to purchase the product.
that's my code
class IAPService {
  void listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    // ignore: avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("purchaseDetails.status ${purchaseDetails.status}");
      }
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
          purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        _handleSuccessfulPurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print(purchaseDetails.error!);
        }
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Purchase marked complete");
        }
      }
    });
  }

at my widger screen that holds the payments not on main.dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getuser();
    futureData = accountController.fetchAccounts();
    final Stream purchaseUpdated = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;
    iapSubscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Purchase stream started");
      }
      IAPService().listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      iapSubscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      iapSubscription.cancel();
    }) as StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>;

    initStoreInfo();
  }

but the open app ads on my homescreen.dart page pops up after I back to my screen
class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {

  AppOpenManager appOpenManager = AppOpenManager();
  bool isPaused = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      isPaused = false;
      appOpenManager.showAdIfAvailable();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      isPaused = true;
    }
  }

so how to force stop that ad I'm using Getx as state management, can anyone help me please

I did it,
I added check value before loading the ad
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (userController.getuser!.ads) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        isPaused = false;
        appOpenManager.showAdIfAvailable();
      } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        isPaused = true;
      }
    }
  }

